# Datatool, Two DB rows per table row, vertically ordered

Tags: tables, datatool

So after searching for some hours I'm surprised that there wasn't any useful solution to find.

I import a CSV table using `datatool`. That table only consists of 3 narrow columns, but I got a lot of rows. I followed the example in the documentation to get two rows in one table row next to each other.

So far that works fine but unfortunately the values read from left to right and not left side top to down and then on the right half top to down.

Let me illustrate my Problem:

```
|---|---|---|---|
| # |foo| # |foo|
|===|===|===|===|
| 1 |abc| 2 |def|
| 3 |ghi| 4 |jkl|
| 5 |mno| 6 |pqr|
|---|---|---|---|
```

That's how it is now following the documentation (Example 8, page 47 in [`datatool.pdf`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool.pdf)).

What I want to have is

```
|---|---|---|---|
| # |foo| # |foo|
|===|===|===|===|
| 1 |abc| 4 |jkl|
| 2 |def| 5 |mno|
| 3 |ghi| 6 |pqr|
|---|---|---|---|
```

Is there any chance to modify that example to give an output like that?

**Minimal example**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={id,item}]{test_db}{test.csv}


\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Two database rows per tabular row}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
    \bfseries ID &
    \bfseries Item &
    \bfseries ID &
    \bfseries Item
    \DTLforeach*{test_db}{\id=id,\item=item}{%
        \DTLifoddrow{\\}{&}%
        \id & \item}%
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

With `test.csv` filled with the following

```
1;abc
2;def
3;ghi
4;jkl
5;mno
6;pqr
```

Comment: Hi aaron, [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Could you place, as a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), the code that gives you the result you mention? This gives the wizards a starting point they can copy and paste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={id,item}]{test_db}{test.csv}



\begin{table}[htbp]
   \count2=\DTLrowcount{test_db}
   \count4 = \count2
   \divide\count4 by 2
   \count2=\count4
   \advance\count2 by 1

    \caption{Two database rows per tabular row}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
    \bfseries ID &
    \bfseries Item &
    \bfseries ID &
    \bfseries Item
    \DTLforeach*[\id<\count2]{test_db}{\id=id,\item=item}{%
       \\
        \id & \item
   \count0=\id
   \advance\count0 by \count4
    \DTLforeach*[\id=\count0]{test_db}{\id=id,\item=item}{%
      &\id &\item}
}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me a lot. I modified your code a little bit to also support an odd number of rows in the CSV file. It probably could be done nicer, but I'm just starting to use LaTeX so I'm happy to just get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Table with odd number of rows]

With the help of David Carlisle I managed to solve it. I modified his code a little bit to also support an odd number of rows in the CSV file.
My modification is probably not the best way to do it, but I'm just getting started with LaTeX and it is so not like what I'm used to when it comes to programming.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={id,item}]{test_db}{test.csv}

\DTLrowcount{test_db}

\begin{table}[htbp]
   \count2=\DTLrowcount{test_db}
   \count4 = \count2
   \divide\count4 by 2
   \count2=\count4

    %%% modification start
    \count10=\count2
    \advance\count10 by \count4

    \ifnum\count10=\DTLrowcount{test_db}
        %even number of entries 
        \advance\count2 by 1
    \else
        %odd number of entries
        \advance\count2 by 2
        \advance\count4 by 1
    \fi
    %%% modification end

    \caption{Two database rows per tabular row}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
    \bfseries ID &
    \bfseries Item &
    \bfseries ID &
    \bfseries Item
    \DTLforeach*[\id<\count2]{test_db}{\id=id,\item=item}{%
       \\
        \id & \item
   \count0=\id
   \advance\count0 by \count4
    \DTLforeach*[\id=\count0]{test_db}{\id=id,\item=item}{%
      &\id &\item}
}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach which is more efficient as it only uses a simple `\loop` rather than nested instances of `\DTLforeach*`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={id,item}]{test_db}{test.csv}
\newcount\mididx
\mididx=\numexpr\DTLrowcount{test_db}/2\relax

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{Two database rows per tabular row}
  \centering
  \newcommand\tabcontents{\bfseries ID & \bfseries Item & 
  \bfseries ID & \bfseries Item}%
  \count2=0\relax
  \loop
  \advance\count2 by 1\relax
  \DTLassign{test_db}{\count2}{\Id=id,\Item=item}%
  \eappto\tabcontents{\noexpand\\\expandonce\Id \noexpand & \expandonce\Item}%
  \count4=\numexpr\count2+\mididx\relax
  \ifnum\count4>\DTLrowcount{test_db}
  \else
    \DTLassign{test_db}{\count4}{\Id=id,\Item=item}%
    \eappto\tabcontents{\noexpand& \expandonce\Id \noexpand& \expandonce\Item}%
  \fi
  \ifnum\count2<\mididx
  \repeat
  \begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
  \tabcontents
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

To avoid complications of looping within a tabular context, this uses `\loop` to construct a control sequence (`\tabcontents`) to contain the tabular contents, and then it just places `\tabcontents` within the `tabular` environment. (`\eappto` is provided by `etoolbox`, which is automatically loaded by `datatool`.)